# Is it safe to disable rsyslog if I have journald?

Tags: debian, logging, rsyslog, journald

I am using Debian 10. It seems to me, that both `journald` and `(r)syslogd` watch for messages independently from sources such as `kmesg()` or `syslog()`.

Is there any advantage to running both? Why does Debian ship with both? For comfort? I guess syslog files can be `cat`'d, where as `journald` forces you to use `journalctl`?

I do not want to ship my logs remotely and I have enabled journald's persistence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe. I have uninstalled `rsyslog` on all my Debian running personal computers. Yet in such a scenario you have done the right move I believe to change `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, line `Storage=auto` to `Storage=persistent` to keep older journals, not only the current after boot, which is the default setting in Debian 10.

On the other hand, on servers you could leave it for better handling of logs; perhaps to redirect them to a log server as you mentioned. Since you don't need this feature, you could unistall it or disable it from servers also.